# Use generic Wildcard in interface level java

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

This is related to java generic wild card. I need to understand how this happens and need solution.

Ex : I have a interface names Processer.

```
public interface Processer<X> {
    <P> void process(P parent, X result);
}
```

I want to make P as wildcard. but it is not allowed to use wildcard ( ? ) when defining.

When I implement this interface and let IDE to generate implemented methods it generate as follow.

```
public class FirstProcesser implements Processer<String> {
    @Override
    public <P> void process(P parent, String result) {

    }
}
```

I want to modify this implementation as this.

```
public class FirstProcesser implements Processer<String> {
    @Override
    public void process(User parent, String result) {

    }
}
```

But it gives compile errors that FirstProcesser should be abstract or implement all the abstract methods.

I need to know why this is happening and a solution.

Comment: Seems pretty obvious *why* it's happening. `User` and `P` aren't (necessarily) the same type, so it's an invalid override. If you want a solution, you'll need to be clearer about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: since P is represent generic P can be anything. am i correct ?

Comment: In the sense that you can *call* it with any particular `P`. Not that you can *override* it with any `P`.

Comment: If you had `Processor<String> processor = ...`, the value could be either `FirstProcessor`, `SecondProcessor`, etc... If we were to call `processor.process(..., "")`, what enforces the first argument to be `User`? `FirstProcessor` tries to enforce it, but what if the value of `processor` switched from `FirstProcessor` to `SecondProcessor`, and `SecondProcessor` wanted to accept a different value other than `User` (which is probably why you're doing this, otherwise `P` could just be `User`)? It wouldn't make sense, which is why it's not allowed.

Comment: thanks for the comment. this issue came to me when i implement some thing like chain of responsibility pattern. so i have implement this is super class and use it. then process bind relevant processor to next responsibility accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

### Overriding

You can't override a method
(generic or not)
with one that takes a narrower parameter type.
If you could, it would be impossible for the compiler to tell whether any given method call would be
(future tense)
legal.

An example without any generics at all, which will fail with exactly the same error:

```
public class X {
    public void f(Object o) {
    }
}

class Y extends X {
    @Override
    public void f(String s) {
    }
}
```

Compiling this fails with:

```
X.java:8: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
1 error
```

If it were legal, then it would be impossible to reliably compile even very simple methods like:

```
public static void f(X x) {
    x.f(5);
}
```

If `x` were an actual `X` object, that code would work fine, but if `x` were a `Y` subtype, it would fail, because `5` is not a `String`.
This is why the above definition of `Y.f` is not allowed to override `X.f`.

By changing `FirstProcesser` to accept only `User` objects, you are causing the same problem.

### Chain of Responsibility

The
[chain of responsibility pattern on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)
doesn't look much like what you're trying to build.
I can think of two things you might be trying to do...

1.
If the `parent` parameter is supposed to be the previous handler in the chain, then it should be of type `Processer<X>`:

```
public interface Processer<X> {
    void process(Processer<X> parent, X result);
}

class StringProcesser implements Processer<String> {
    @Override
    public void process(Processer<String> parent, String result) {
    }
}
```

2.
If the type of `parent` is part of the decision-making process, each handler should store a collection of the `Class` objects it can handle.
The `process` method should then see if `parent.getClass()` is in that collection.

A partial definition might look something like:

```
public interface Processer<X> {
    void process(Class<?> parent, X result);
}

class StringProcesser implements Processer<String> {
    private Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public StringProcesser(final Iterable<Class<?>> classes) {
        for (final Class<?> c : classes) {
            this.classes.add(c);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Class<?> parent, String result) {
        if (this.classes.contains(parent)) {
            System.err.println("Handling...");
            System.out.println(result);
            return;
        }
        System.err.println(
          "Can't handle.  Try next Processer."
        );
        // ...
    }

}
```

Note that where the generic type parameter `<X>` and where the wildcard `<?>` show up depends on what you're trying to do.

PS:  "Processer" should be spelled "Processor".