# Java generic wildcard usages

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

This is related to java generic wild card.

I have interface like this.

```
public interface Processer<P, X> {
    void process(P parent, X result);
}
```

An implementation like this.

```
public class FirstProcesser implements Processer<User, String> {
    @Override
    public void process(User parent, String result) {

    }
}
```

And I'm using processer as this.

```
public class Executor {
    private Processer<?, String> processer;

    private  int i;
    public void setProcesser(Processer<?, String> processer) {
        this.processer = processer;
    }

    private String generateString() {
        return "String " + i++;
    }

    public <P> void execute(P parent) {
        processer.process(parent, generateString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Executor executor = new Executor();
        executor.setProcesser(new FirstProcesser());
        User user = new User();
        executor.execute(user);
    }
}
```

But here

```
public <P> void execute(P parent) {
    processer.process(parent, generateString());
}
```

it gives compile error Error:(18, 27) java: incompatible types: P cannot be converted to capture#1 of ?

I need to understand why this give an error. also solution.

Comment: It's not possible to pass anything besides null to a parameter of type `?`. Btw `<P> void execute(P parent)` is basically equivalent to `void execute(Object parent)`.

Comment: What are Processer and Executor supposed to do? What are their purposes?

Comment: Related:  An earlier version of this question, "[Use generic Wildcard in interface level java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807833)".

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard basically means "I don't care which type is used here". In your case, you definitely do care though: the first type parameter of your processor must be the same as the `P` type in the execute method.

With the current code, you could call `execute(1)`, which would try to call the FirstProcesser with an integer as argument, which obviously makes no sense, hence why the compiler forbids it.

The easiest solution would be to make your Executor class generic, instead of only the execute method:

```
public class Executor<P> {
    private Processer<P, String> processer;

    private int i;
    public void setProcesser(Processer<P, String> processer) {
        this.processer = processer;
    }

    private String generateString() {
        return "String " + i++;
    }

    public void execute(P parent) {
        processer.process(parent, generateString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Executor executor = new Executor<User>();
        executor.setProcesser(new FirstProcesser());
        User user = new User();
        executor.execute(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes. i can do this. but problem is huge no of Executor usages there. also in third party apps. its not practically to do this. thanks for solution.

Comment: If the class is being used in a lot of places already, what does it look like at the moment then? And what are you trying to accomplish with the changes?

Comment: this is some issue i face once i do some modification. this is not the whole class. this example related to new changes i had try to made. i have already solve this another way. but i want to know why this happening. and some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because `processor` can have first type argument of anything.  You may have assigned a `Process<Foo, String>` to it, and of course compiler will complain as it can be something different from `P` in your `execute()`.

You may want to make your `Executor` a generic class:

```
class Executor<T> {
    private Processer<T, String> processer;

    public void setProcesser(Processer<T, String> processer) {
        this.processer = processer;
    }

    public void execute(T parent) {
        processer.process(parent, generateString());
    }
}
```

and your `main` will look like:

```
    Executor<User> executor = new Executor<User>();
    executor.setProcesser(new FirstProcesser());
    User user = new User();
    executor.execute(user);
```

---

In response to comments:

There is no proper solution with proper use of Generics here, because what you are doing is contradicting: On one hand you say you do not care about first type argument of `Processor` (hence `private Processor<?, String> processor`), but on the other hand you DO really care about it (your `execute`).  Compiler is simply doing its work right as it is absolutely legal for you to assign a `Processor<Foo,String>` to it.

If you don't really care about generics and is willing to suffer from poor design, then don't use generics.

Just keep `Processor` a raw type in `Executor` and suppress all unchecked warning:

i.e.

```
class Executor {
    private Processor processor;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setProcessor(Processor<?, String> processor) {
        this.processor = processor;
    }

    // your generic method does not do any meaningful check.
    // just pass an Object to it
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void execute(Object parent) {
        processor.process(parent, "");
    }
}
```

And if it is me, I will go one step further:

Provide an Executor that is properly designed (e.g. calling it `TypedExecutor`).  All new code should use the new, properly designed `TypedExecutor`.  Original `Executor` is kept for sake of backward compatibility, and delegate its work to `TypedExecutor`.

Hence look like:

```
class TypedExecutor<T> {
    private Processor<T, String> processor;

    public void setProcessor(Processor<T, String> processor) {
        this.processor = processor;
    }

    public void execute(T parent) {
        processor.process(parent, "");
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
class Executor {
    private TypedExecutor executor = new TypedExecutor();

    public void setProcessor(Processor<?, String> processor) {
        this.executor.setProcessor(processor);
    }

    public void execute(Object parent) {
        this.executor.execute(parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes. i can do this. but problem is huge no of Executor usages there. also in third party apps. its not practically to do this. thanks for solution.

Comment: thanks for solution. suppose if this Executor already already have so many usages. then its difficult apply generics here. is it. then what would be the solution ?

Comment: No other proper solution I can think of, unless you are willing to have poor design.

Comment: I just don't understand: What's the point using generics in your case? Why not just use `Processor` as raw type in `Executor`, and do `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` in all affected functions?